# Download a part of youtube video using a powershell script

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I'm writing this Powershell script:

```
$URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbuwueqEJL0"
$from = 00:06:15
$to = 00:09:17

$cmdOutput = (youtube-dl --get-url $URL) 

ffmpeg -ss $from -to $to -i <video_url> -ss $from -to $to -i <audio_url> output.mkv
```

This script's purpose is to download a part of a Youtube video. I've set the variable $URL to specify the Youtube URL, while `$from` and `$to` is the start and end time of the part I want to download.

`$cmdOutput` is used to output the stream URL. The output would have two lines: the first one is the URL for the video stream, while the second one is the audio stream URL.

Currently, I don't know how to use the output as a variable and specify the line number of $cmdOutput to put it into the correct stream. I guess `<video_url>` and `<audio_url>` would be replaced by something like `$cmdOutput[line 1]`, and `$cmdOutput[line 2]`, though I know that those are incorrect.

I've consulted [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1661048/how-to-download-a-portion-of-a-youtube-video), and it is handy for me to write this script. I've also read [Boris Lipschitz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131049/is-it-possible-to-download-a-specific-part-of-a-file) on how to do the same thing with Python, but his answer does not work.

In that script, the `-ss <start_time>` flag inputs the seeking point, and the `-t <duration>` flag tells FFmpeg to stop encoding after the specified duration. For example, if the start time is 00:02:00 and the duration is 00:03:00, FFmpeg would download from 00:02:00 to 00:05:00, which is not the expected outcome. For some reason, his Python script skips the first 5 seconds of output, even if I replace the `-t` flag with `-to <end_time>`. I've tried to edit his script, but it does not work unless you explicitly specify the time for both video and audio stream, as well as their respective stream URL.

Comment: Can you give an example of the value for ```$cmdOutput``` (you can add ```write-host $cmdOutput``` to see it displayed in the console output) and what you'd expect the values for ```<video_url>``` and ```<audio_url>``` to be as a result? (Update your question with the information rather than reply in comments).

Comment: @mclayton For example, I want to get the stream URL for the youtube video above. I would use `youtube-dl --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbuwueqEJL0` to get the URL for the streams and the program would output two lines with two different URLs, one for the video stream and one for the audio stream. [This is the output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NzqdDYT2Dd/) I would get.

Comment: @mclayton If you look at the third paragraph after the script's code block, you should find my example about `$cmdOutput` there.

Comment: I don't have the ```youtube-dl``` module installed locally, so I can't run your script to get the output. If you can post the *actual values* you might find someone is able to help, but I'm not personally able to assist any further without concrete values in your question...