# How to download video by url using ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I'm trying to write script that will be downloading part of youtube video by url. I'm using `ffmpeg` + `ffmpeg-python` library.

I have terminal command that I want put to python code.

```
ffmpeg -i "url_to_download" -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:25 -c:v copy -c:a copy "demo.mp4"
```

`url_to_download` is an youtube stream url that I get like in an answer to another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134397/6583203

I started writing script

```py
import ffmpeg

FROM = "00:00:15"
TO = "00:00:25"
TARGET = "demo.mp4"

ffmpeg.input(url_to_download, ss=FROM, t=TO)
```

But I don't know how to pass parameters `-c:v copy -c:a copy "demo.mp4"` to `ffmpeg.input`

Do not advice me to use  `subprocess`. I have the same error like in a following question: [Python ffmpeg won't accept path, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836756/python-ffmpeg-wont-accept-path-wh)

Comment: Try: `ffmpeg.input(url_to_download, ss=FROM, t=TO).output("demo.mp4", vcodec="copy", acodec="copy").overwrite_output().run()`

Comment: @Rotem It works, thanks! You can write this as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: @Rotem if you will add link where I can read about it more, it would be helpful too

Comment: There are 2 or 3 formal documentation pages - just use Google. Most of the information is found in FFmpeg documentation, but getting from FFmpeg command line syntax to ffmpeg-python requires some practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer worked for me

```py
ffmpeg.input(url_to_download, ss=FROM, t=TO).output("demo.mp4", vcodec="copy", acodec="copy").overwrite_output().run()
```